# Check All Occurrences and Update

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of 200k rows that have 27k distinct person_identifier values in it. On each row there is a 'value' column and a 'complete' column. I am trying to update the 'complete' column to a yes if every single row for a person_identifier has a NOT NULL value.

Take this example:

| person id | value | complete |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23 |  |
| 1 | 22 |  |
| 1 | NULL |  |
| 2 | 88 |  |
| 2 | 22 |  |
| 3 | 46 |  |
| 3 | 78 |  |
| 4 | NULL |  |
| 4 | NULL |  |

In this example I would want complete to be 'yes' for person 2 and 3, but not for 1 and 4 since they have at least 1 NULL value

Comment: what have you tried?  I would start with a select statement that had person id and the new complete value and work until you have that correct.  Then you can use that in an update.

Comment: @ScottMildenberger The issue I am having is where they overlap. I for example do SELECT * FROM table WHERE value IS NULL AND person_id IS NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT person_id FROM table WHERE value is NOT NULL). The should I think give me people who have both a NULL and a NOT NULL correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem by inverting your reasoning. Follow these steps:

- select all those "*person id*" values who have at least one NULL value
- left join this selection with your table
- update only those rows which have NULL as a result of the outer join

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT [person id]
    FROM tab
    WHERE [value] IS NULL
)
UPDATE tab
SET complete = 'yes'
FROM      tab 
LEFT JOIN cte ON tab.[person id] = cte.[person id]
WHERE cte.[person id] IS NULL;
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Eb2TFH45).

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` statement with `COUNT` in a subquery:

```
UPDATE a
SET complete = CASE 
                 WHEN (SELECT COUNT(person_id) FROM sampleTable WHERE value IS NULL AND person_id = a.person_id) > 0 THEN 'no'
                 ELSE 'yes'
               END
FROM sampleTable a
```

**Result:**

```
| person_id | value | complete  |
|-----------|-------|-----------|
| 1         | 23    | no        |
| 1         | 22    | no        |
| 1         | null  | no        |
| 2         | 88    | yes       |
| 2         | 22    | yes       |
| 3         | 46    | yes       |
| 3         | 78    | yes       |
| 4         | null  | no        |
| 4         | null  | no        |
```

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/6A2ZhNFT).